# Testing for a Thrown Entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have come across some troubles lately. I was trying to come up with a command to find an item that a player throws on the ground, however it is slightly more complicated because it is a yellow stained glass pane (the trouble I am having is that I cannot get it to detect the colour yellow).

The current command I am using to test for the stained glass pane is this:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:minecraft:stained_glass_pane,Damage:4}}
```

I ran the command (in a repeating command block) and get no error response, but when I throw the yellow stained glass pane onto the ground, the command block doesn't react or give an output signal. If I remove the `,Damage:4` portion of the command, the command block will give an output if any glass pane is thrown.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `testfor` instead of a `scoreboard` command?  The reason I ask is because `testfor` is mostly useless, except for some edge cases that 1.9 and conditional command blocks open up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When checking pre-existing NBT data, such as for `/testfor`, `/scoreboard`, or `/testforblock`, you must specify all data exactly as it's stored. This includes datatypes; you've declared `Damage` as an Integer, when instead it's saved as a Short. To declare it as a Short, you must append the value with an `s`:

```
/testfor @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:stained_glass_pane",Damage:4s}}
```